# Does 'in somma' directly descend from the Latin 'ad summum"

Tags: etymology

One of the favorite Italian filler words, that is, what you say when you're gathering your thoughts, is 'in somma'.  It occurs to me that in basically the only text which purports to faithfully reproduce the Latin colloquial, the Satyricon, one of the characters does use 'ad summum' is his filler expression.  Is 'in somma' as a filler expression a modern development or is it possible that this has been the go to filler expression on the Italian peninsula for 2000 years?

I realize we don't have any colloquially written Italian for a very long time and that by 1950 only 2% of the population was speaking the Italian used today, still, if any colloquial is found that is very old and 'in summa' is in there that might be good evidence that this filler expression never died out from the 1st century.

Comment: I forgot: this may help: https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/8?seq=139

Answer (score 2):

In modern Italian it's spelt as a single word (*insomma*).

As to its origins, dictionaries give as its origin *in somma*, either as a Latin or an Italian phrase.

Notice that a *somma* is the result of an addition (a “sum”): with *insomma* you're summing up your conclusions, basically. Latin *ad summum*, on the other hand, means “toward the highest point”, or figuratively “to the utmost”; see for instance https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_latino/Latino/S/summum_1.shtml

(*Somma* in the meaning of “sum” comes itself indirectly from the same adjective *summus*, but through a longer path.)

Comment: Thanks but you answered a different question. My question is not: "is the meaning of 'insomma' similar to the meaning of 'ad summum?'" rather my question is: do we have any evidence that 'insomma' has been a filler expression (an expression you say when you're collecting your thoughts) for as long as we've had records of that type of speech act?

Comment: @bobsmith76 Thanks for clarifying, but I'm not sure I understand yet. As for “this filler expression never died out from the 1st century”, the premise is false since _insomma_ didn't exist in the 1st century; according to Zingarelli it dates from about 1261. If you're asking about all kinds of “filler expression” of this general kind, in both Latin and Italian, the question seems off topic about Latin (but there is a SE about Latin) and quite broad about Italian.

Comment: And anyhow, I see now that I was somehow answering to the question as phrased in the title: “Does 'in somma' directly descend from the Latin 'ad summum"”, and I have shown that the answer is “no”.

Comment: The filler expression used by some people of the Italian peninsula in the first century CE was 'ad summum', at least given the minor evidence that we have.  So what I'm trying to figure out is if that expression remained the filler expression of the people of the Italian Peninsula except that a few syllables were slightly altered.   The fact that 'insomma' dates from 1261 does not help things because we need to know if it was used a filler expression.  Of course we have no evidence of what the filler expression was for a very long time.  But if it can be shown that

Comment: 'insomma' only recently became a filler expression in the last 30 years or so that that at least would be evidence against the theory.

Comment: A good place to start would be that we at least have recorded Italian that is easily accessible from movies in the 1930s, (I imagine we have audios earlier but they might be harder to find), if there is no evidence that 'insomma' is used as a filler expression in those movies then that would show that there was an interruption of the use of the filler expression on the Italian Peninsula.  It used to be 'ad summum' then it died out, then it came back mysteriously several hundred years later or it was just a coincidence.

Comment: @bobsmith76: I think I understand better now, thanks. There are two different issues here. 1) _Ad summum_ and _insomma_ have nothing to do with each other, so there is no possible continuity among them. They're not the same “except that a few syllables were slightly altered”: they're different phrases, consisting of a different preposition and a different noun, with a different meaning.

Comment: 2) As for studying the diachronic use of _insomma_, that's a different question, and a quite interesting one. I'm less pessimistic than you about finding reliable sources. Far before actual recordings, good novelists from Boccaccio to Manzoni and Pirandello (to mention just three especially great ones) had a keen ear for spoken language, so we could, at least in a first approximation, search for instances of _insomma_ in their work.

Comment: Well, I disagree about 'ad summum' and 'insomma' being completely unrelated.  In the key passage in the Satyricon in which it is used it's obvious that the speaker is just using it as a favorite expression that he uses when he's gathering his thoughts, exactly as 'insomma' is used today, sort of like in English when someone says 'if you will'.   As for Boccaccio recording colloquial speech, well, what did he record?  Did he record anything that looks like a filler expression?  If so, what was it?

Comment: I have now checked _Satyricon_ text (http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/petronius1.html), which admittedly I should have done first. It's not _ad summum_ but _ad summam_, which is quite different, and indeed lends more strength to your guess of a precursor to _insomma_. But, please, be accurate in your quotations, lest you send people on a wild goose chase!  :)

Comment: As for Boccaccio, he doesn't actually seem to use _insomma_ in his _Decameron_ (https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Decameron), and _in somma_ only in a non-relevant context (“in somma lode del re”), but he was just an example. I was saying that if one is interested in the history of a word or phrase in colloquial Italian, good novelists are a valuable source.